# JPA 2 CriteriaQuery order by index

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, criteria-api

I have an Entity with a `List<EntityRevision>` contained in it.  The collection has an `@OrderColumn`.

I'd like to get all the `EntityRevisions` for an Entity ordered by their index.

I can do this with the following query:

```
SELECT er 
  FROM Entity e JOIN e.revisions er 
  WHERE e.id = :entityId 
  ORDER BY index(er)
```

But I can't figure out how to do this with the `CriteriaQuery`.

Using EclipseLink 2.3.2 / JPA 2.0.3 - the `Root<EntityRevision>` has no `index()` method on it that I can use in the orderBy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested it, but something like 
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc( ((ListJoin)root.get("listMapping")).index()));
should work if your listMapping is a list with an orderby column.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
final EntityManager m = ...
final CriteriaBuilder b = m.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Child> q = b.createQuery( Child.class );
final Root<Parent> p = q.from( Parent.class );
final ListJoin<Parent, Child> j = p.join( Parent_.children );
final CriteriaQuery<Child> s = q.select( j );

s.where( b.equal( j.get( Child_.parent ), parent ) );
s.orderBy( b.asc( j.index() ) );

final TypedQuery<Child> t = m.createQuery( s );
final List<Child> children = t.getResultList();

Assert.assertEquals( parent.getChildren().size(), children.size() );
Assert.assertEquals( parent.getChildren(), children );
```